# Fastest platform/language independent hash implementations

Tags: javascript, java, algorithm, hash

I've been looking for a fast hashing algorithm and came across [xxHash](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash) which has worked well. The only problem is that I need to use this hashing across multiple languages, currently Java + JavaScript. xxHash bindings appear to generate different values in different languages, so I guess it's not portable?

What are some language-independent hash algorithms? An example I had previously was MD5, but it's just so slow in comparison to `Murmur/Farmhash/xxHash`. As shown by the answers here, there are plenty of portable **but slow** algorithms, such as MD5 - which is why I have made it clear that fast speeds are important to me.

Please note that I don't need anything cryptographic, I'm hashing for uniqueness.

---

**Edit:**

I don't believe this is off-topic and asking for opinions; I want solid benchmarks proving the algorithms are fast, and I asked for a language independent algorithm, both of which remove opinion as a valid source of information.

Comment: It's strange, `xxhash` bindings are not supposed to generate different hash values. They should all be identical.
There are 2 versions, xxh32 and xxh64. Ensure you compare similar versions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using nodejs, I'd recommend using ones that have native support. You'd benefit from future updates of these implementations.

The list is here: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

And they are pretty standard algorithms so you can find it in almost any programing language, like java or c.

In node, you can call `require('crypto').getHashes()` and see the list of supported hashes.

I ran it on my computer and the result was:

```
[ 'DSA',
  'DSA-SHA',
  'DSA-SHA1',
  'DSA-SHA1-old',
  'RSA-MD4',
  'RSA-MD5',
  'RSA-MDC2',
  'RSA-RIPEMD160',
  'RSA-SHA',
  'RSA-SHA1',
  'RSA-SHA1-2',
  'RSA-SHA224',
  'RSA-SHA256',
  'RSA-SHA384',
  'RSA-SHA512',
  'dsaEncryption',
  'dsaWithSHA',
  'dsaWithSHA1',
  'dss1',
  'ecdsa-with-SHA1',
  'md4',
  'md4WithRSAEncryption',
  'md5',
  'md5WithRSAEncryption',
  'mdc2',
  'mdc2WithRSA',
  'ripemd',
  'ripemd160',
  'ripemd160WithRSA',
  'rmd160',
  'sha',
  'sha1',
  'sha1WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha224',
  'sha224WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha256',
  'sha256WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha384',
  'sha384WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha512',
  'sha512WithRSAEncryption',
  'shaWithRSAEncryption',
  'ssl2-md5',
  'ssl3-md5',
  'ssl3-sha1',
  'whirlpool' ]
```

I'm using node v4.2.1.

You can also use [cryptojs](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/). The list of hashing algorithms supported by cryptojs is here: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Hasher_Algorithms

Comment: Which hashing algs are supported in the built in native module?

Comment: Just updated my answer to provide list of supported hashes.

Comment: This really doesn't answer my question though, because I'm asking for language independent. Although they're likely to be supported on other platforms, they're also very slow algorithms.